# What is wrong with this short C code

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to scan input, if user types "yes" put "etc" otherwise exit. But it's not working right, when i type yes it says invalid instead. Thanks ahead of time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char yes='yes';
char name[100];


int main()

{

    puts("Starting History Project please Enter your name: ");

    scanf("%s",&name);

    printf("Hey %s!",name);

    puts("My name is C! Are you interested about my history? yes or no");



    scanf("%s", &yes);
    if (yes == 'yes')
    {
        printf("Starting ADT \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid\n");
        exit(0);

    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: char yes='yes';??? Fix one-by-one from the top.

Comment: This is `scanf("%s",&name);` and `if (yes == 'yes')`   ...?? Too Many mistakes. --Off-topic

Comment: In future perhaps set your compiler warning level high, and fix all warnings *before* posting a question!

Answer (score 2):

The variable yes is a char and as such can only hold one character or an escape sequence. Comparing a char to 'yes' is like comparing the letter 'y' to "yes". 'yes' is illegal, it is a string and cannot have single quotes. You should use `0 == strcmp(inputStr, "yes")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

My compiler pushes out the following warnings, perhaps you should fix them?

```
foo.c:2:10: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
char yes='yes';
         ^
foo.c:2:10: warning: implicit conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from 7955827 to 115
      [-Wconstant-conversion]
char yes='yes';
     ~~~ ^~~~~
foo.c:12:16: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[100]' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%s",&name);
           ~~  ^~~~~
foo.c:21:16: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
    if (yes == 'yes')
               ^
foo.c:21:13: warning: comparison of constant 7955827 with expression of type 'char' is always false
      [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
    if (yes == 'yes')
        ~~~ ^  ~~~~~
foo.c:28:9: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'exit' with type 'void (int) __attribute__((noreturn))'
        exit(0);
        ^
foo.c:28:9: note: please include the header <stdlib.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'exit'
6 warnings generated.
```

Also,

1. `==` does not do string comparison in C.
2. You have not allocated space for the `yes` question.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `&` in scanf. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score 0):

If `yes` is to receive a string, then you should define it as a string, as you have for `name`.

char yes[32] ;

for example.

In the test:

```
 if (yes == 'yes')
```

the `'` delimiter is for *character constants* not for string constants - you need `"` for that.

Moreover in C a string is not a *first class datatype* so you cannot simply test for equality with the `==` operator.  Instead toy need library support for string operations (or test character by character):

```
if( strcmp( yes, "yes" ) )
```

In the `scanf` call itself the identifier `name` is already an address, the `&` is not required and will in fact result in incorrect behaviour.

Comment: Your code beneath the if statement with strcmp(yes, "yes") will not execute if the string variable yes is indeed "yes" because it will evaluate to 0.

Comment: @ChrisZhang:  Given the OP's declaration of `yes` that is true, but that is another error.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char name[100];
    char input[16];

    puts("Starting History Project please Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    printf("Hey %s! ", name);

    puts("My name is C! Are you interested about my history? yes or no");
    scanf(" %s", input);
    if (!strcmp(input, "yes")){
        printf("Starting ADT \n");
    } else {
        printf("Invalid\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```